# Why following proxy does not bypass X-Frame-Options header?

Tags: apache, iframe, reverse-proxy, x-frame-options

I need to show some sites in a iframe and I cannot do that directly as some of those sites have the header X-Frame-Options set to 'SAMEORIGIN'. As a way to bypass this I tried using an reverse proxy in apache. Below is the my apache configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName google.local
ProxyRequests Off

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/iframe-test

ProxyPass /test http://www.oracle.com/index.html
ProxyPassReverse /test http://www.oracle.com/index.html

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/google.local-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/google.local-access.log combined

<Location *>
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    # Header always append X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM all"
    Header add test-header 'test'
</Location>
```

But still I cannot load the site in iframe and I am getting the error `Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.oracle.com/index.html does not permit cross-origin framing.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the above configuration was that the proxy only worked for http protocol. But as seen in the console error message the external site actually redirect http to https automatically.
So to handle the https requests all it was needed to enable ssl in apache and turn on SSLProxyEngine. To do that,

1. run `sudo a2enmod ssl` on terminal
2. add the line 'SSLProxyEngine On' to the above config

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName google.local

       ProxyRequests On
       ProxyPreserveHost Off
       SSLProxyEngine On

       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/iframe-test

       ProxyPass /test http://www.oracle.com/index.html
       ProxyPassReverse /test http://www.oracle.com/index.html

       ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/google.local-error.log
       CustomLog /var/log/apache2/google.local-access.log combined

       <Location *>
           AllowOverride All
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
           # Header always append X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM all"
           Header add test-header 'test'
       </Location>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```